# How to consume JMS messages from the websphere application server using Spring JMS

Tags: java, jms, websphere, spring-jms

I am trying to consume JMS messages from a queue which is defined as JNDI in the WebSphere application server.

Is it possible to connect websphere JMS JNDI using Spring JMS without using the websphere related JARs in the spring MVC application

Answer (score 0):

No; the JNDI support classes (initial context etc) are provided by the JMS provider (in this case IBM); they use proprietary protocols to talk to the server.

Comment: I couldn't find any clue on how to call IBM MQ JNDI from spring JMS.